# Proving $B=\{f:f\in C_{[0,1]}\text{ and }\:d(f,0)\leqslant 1\}$ is not compact

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> Let $(C_{[0,1]},d)$ be the metric space defined with the supremum metric.
>   Let $B=\{f:f\in C_{[0,1]}\text{ and}\:d(f,0)\leqslant 1\}$ where $0$ denotes the constant function form $[0,1]$ into $\mathbb{R}$.
>
> Prove that $B$ is not compact.

Since we are working on a metric space I can use the compactness definition that every convergent sequence has a convergent subsequence so I am trying to find a function that acts as a counterexample to prove the space is not compact.

**Question:**

Is my strategy right? If so, how should I find the sequence of functions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can indeed use a sequence, e.g.  $f_n(x) = x^n$ is a good candidate.

Comment: Could you please explain me how should I use those functions?  I am not seeing how to apply the sequence subsequence definition of compactness, so I think I need to see an example. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Use that a supremum metric (sub)sequence limit is in particular a pointwise one. @PedroGomes

Comment: So if I pick $x^n$, then for $n>N d(x^n,0)=\sup|x^n-0|<\epsilon$ for $\epsilon>x^N$. However I am not seeing how to relate to the compactness concept.

Comment: The point is that these sequences do not converge to a $continuous$ function. i.e. they are sequences in $C$ with no convergent subsequences (in $C!$)

Comment: @PedroGomes The pointwise limit of $x^n$ is $0$ on $[0,1)$ and $1$ on $1$. The sup limit of a sequence of continuous functions is continuous.